# Socket.IO: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting"

Tags: node.js, socket.io, callback

im trying to create a login system with Node.js, Socket.IO and MongoDB.
At one point i have to get a certain cookie of the client.
So i "send" an event to the client which should return the cookie so i can work with that data within the same function.
My code is as follows:

Server:

```
async function checklogin(user) {
    user = user;
    console.log("user:", user);
    await User.find({username:user}).then(function(docs) {
        servercookieid = docs[0].cookieid;
        servercookiedate = docs[0].cookiedate;
    });
    io.emit('getCookie', function(responseData) {
        console.log(responseData)
    }).catch(error)
}
```

Client:

```
socket.on('getCookie', function(callback) {
    console.log('getting cookie...');
    var Cookie = document.cookie;
    callback(Cookie)
});
```

I really dont know why i get this error, because as you can see i am not even broadcasting, sooo...
/shrug

If you need more information, please dont hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says:

> Socket.IO: “UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Callbacks are not
>   supported when broadcasting”
>   But in fact when you do `io.emit` you're broadcasting.

Currently you're broadcasting when you do the command:

```
io.emit('getCookie', function(responseData) {
    console.log(responseData)
}).catch(error)
```

But for broadcasting you just need set a parameter, it's not a function.
Just fix your code to fix the error.
Changing to:

```
io.emit('getCookie', responseData);//must set the cookie
```

by the code you provided `responseData` is not defined. But by the name it should be a cookie.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to tell me.
I dont want to set a cookie, i want to get a cookie from a client, then work with it further in the same function.
With the code you provided, i just send 'getCookie' with any data from the server, but i want to send 'getCookie', then get data back from the client to the server

Comment: You must not use `socket.emit` same way you 're doing in `socket.on`. You shouldn't put a function when emitting. Here is the documentation. https://socket.io/docs/#Sending-and-getting-data-acknowledgements